# Track an operation in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

My dataframes

df1:

> ```
> Index                 Amount               
> 01.01.2018 08:00:00   23.25
> 01.01.2018 08:10:00   25.50
> 01.01.2018 08:20:00   26.30
> 01.01.2018 08:30:00   25.00
> 01.01.2018 08:40:00   20.00
> 01.01.2018 08:50:00   21.20
> 01.01.2018 09:00:00   21.20
> 01.01.2018 09:10:00   31.20
> ```

df2:

> ```
> Index       Operation
> 01.01.2018  -5.00
> 01.01.2018  10.00
> ```

I'd like to track operations from df2 in my df1.

So basically check Operations in df2, and find where this event happened in df1.
For ex. there is -5.00, and this event happened here:

> ```
> 01.01.2018 08:30:00   25.00
> 01.01.2018 08:40:00   20.00
> ```

My excpected output:

df:

> ```
> Index                 Amount  Operation_T/F  Amount_Operation              
> 01.01.2018 08:00:00   23.25   0              0
> 01.01.2018 08:10:00   25.50   0              0
> 01.01.2018 08:20:00   26.30   0              0
> 01.01.2018 08:30:00   25.00   0              0
> 01.01.2018 08:40:00   20.00   1              -5.0
> 01.01.2018 08:50:00   21.20   0              0
> 01.01.2018 09:00:00   21.20   0              0
> 01.01.2018 09:10:00   31.20   1              10.0
> ```

The fact that operations can be a duplicate during the day is not a problem. 
Of course playing with some for's and if's could be a solution but I am trying to achieve a clean code in python and I'm thinking a way to do it nicer.

Had some issues with writing that `True` or `False` value for operation, `if in row` or `row + 1`. 
My idea to solve that was to create bins for two rows, and then track if operation event occurred in that bin. What do you think?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you better explain what you mean with `I'd like to track operations from df2 in my df1`?

Comment: I'd like to find the Operation -5.00 (df2) in my amount column in df1. It occured in df1 passing from index 01.01.2018 08:30:00 to index 01.01.2018 08:40:00. Sorry for not explaining, i will edit my question.

Comment: I'm guessing the date is important? So there has to be a previous groupby operation?

Comment: You should check the previous value - the current one. Write the Amount_Operation column depending on the result.

Comment: Yes, this is an example for day 01.01.2018, of course df is longer, but the problem is that df2 doesn't have a time index.  I don't want to group by them, just to check where during the day, two operations from df2 happened in df1.

Comment: If the days are different between `df1` and `df2`, should we ignore the day and merge if the difference matches?

Comment: Operation that happened for ex on 02.14.2018 shouldn't be trakced in df1 in day 01.01.2018,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach using [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to check where the first diferences in `df2.Operation` are equal to `df2.Operation` and leveraging [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
m = df1.Amount.diff().values == df2.Operation.values[:,None]
df1['Operation_T/F'] = m.sum(0)
df1['Amount_Operation'] = (m * df2.Operation.values[:,None]).sum(0)

         Index         Amount         Operation_T/F  Amount_Operation
0 2018-01-01 08:00:00   23.25              0               0.0
1 2018-01-01 08:10:00   25.50              0               0.0
2 2018-01-01 08:20:00   26.30              0               0.0
3 2018-01-01 08:30:00   25.00              0               0.0
4 2018-01-01 08:40:00   20.00              1              -5.0
5 2018-01-01 08:50:00   21.20              0               0.0
6 2018-01-01 09:00:00   21.20              0               0.0
7 2018-01-01 09:10:00   31.20              1              10.0
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to account for asserting that the days in the index actually match up with what is being merged.  For example, if you change index `4` to the `2nd`, it still adds an entry

Comment: From what I understood from OPs comments it is not needed: `the problem is that df2 doesn't have a time index. I don't want to group by them` @user3483203

Comment: Later on, he says `I don't want to group by them, just to check where during the day, two operations from df2 happened in df1`. Agree that it's kinda confusing.

Comment: He means no time, but it still has a day. "just to check where during the day"

Comment: What I'm deducing from this is that OP only has values corresponding to 1 day at a given time in `df2`, although you could be right @user3483203

Comment: My df2 cointains only date index, doesn't have information about time. As showed in the question. Sorry my confiused question.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you want to merge on the difference of the Amount and the date:

```
df1['date'] = df1.index.floor('D')
df1['Amount_Operation'] = df1.Amount.diff()


df = (df1.reset_index()
         .merge(df2.reset_index(), 
              left_on=['date', 'Amount_Operation'],
              right_on=['Index','Operation'],
              left_index=True,
              suffixes=['','_y'],
              how='left')
         .drop(['Index_y', 'date'], axis=1)
     )

df['Operation_T/F'] = df.Operation.isna()
df['Amount_Operation'] = df.Operation.fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
                Index  Amount  Amount_Operation  Operation  Operation_T/F
1 2018-01-01 08:00:00   23.25               0.0        NaN           True
1 2018-01-01 08:10:00   25.50               0.0        NaN           True
1 2018-01-01 08:20:00   26.30               0.0        NaN           True
1 2018-01-01 08:30:00   25.00               0.0        NaN           True
0 2018-01-01 08:40:00   20.00              -5.0       -5.0          False
1 2018-01-01 08:50:00   21.20               0.0        NaN           True
1 2018-01-01 09:00:00   21.20               0.0        NaN           True
1 2018-01-01 09:10:00   31.20              10.0       10.0          False
```